# Make a folder for the files placed in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, listview, file, directory

Whats the procedure to send the files placed in a `ListView` to a folder.

I need to place all the files in the `ListView` to a folder on button click event. On button click it should make a folder for all the files in the list view and send them in.

I'm using Winforms in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use Directory.CreateDirectory Method to create a folder.
2. Then use FileStream class to create new file in that folder.
3. Copy the contents/data of the file from database to the file stream
4. When finished close the file stream.
5. Repeat 2-4 for each file.

Comment: can u show me the sample code that will be easier for me to understand...plz show the code using listview..ie files are in the listview

Answer (score 0):

To check if the directory exists, use [Directory.Exists Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) .

To create the directory if it does not exist, use [Directory.CreateDirectory Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory(VS.71).aspx).

To get all files in a directory, use [Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx).

To move files, use [File.Move Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) .

To copy files, use [File.Copy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: thanks sir but its general description on how to make fodlers but my issue is that i have the files in the database and im displaying them in the listview..now next step is i need to make the folder for those files in the listview and i need to have the backup for the files also..what is the method to do that??